# send data from database to form

Tags: c#, database, winforms, devexpress

Friends, I designed a restaurant program, which includes a main or parent form and several sub-forms or child forms that are displayed inside the main form. My main form is Microsoft's standard form. But other forms are `DevExpress`. The problem I have is that when the amount entered in the order form is saved after clicking the payment button, I cannot send the amount saved in the database to the main form through the `DevExpress` form. From the technical point of view and the coding of the method, there is no problem, I just don't know why the data is not sent. While in the load event of the main form, when I call the same method, it runs without any problem. Please advise where the problem could be.

```
public static void ShowFoundBalance(System.Windows.Forms.Label cashCapital, System.Windows.Forms.Label nonCashCapital, System.Windows.Forms.Label totalCapital)
    {
        Domain.DataBaseContext dataBaseContext = null;
        try
        {
            dataBaseContext =
                new Domain.DataBaseContext();

            Domain.CashBox cashBox =
                dataBaseContext.CashBoxes
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (cashBox != null)
            {
                cashCapital.Text = cashBox.CashCapital;
                nonCashCapital.Text = cashBox.NonCashCapital;
                totalCapital.Text = cashBox.TotalCapital;
            }
            else
            {
                cashCapital.Text = $"0 تومان";
                nonCashCapital.Text = $"0 تومان";
                totalCapital.Text = $"0 تومان";
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.ExceptionShow(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dataBaseContext != null)
            {
                dataBaseContext.Dispose();
                dataBaseContext = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the method that should display the balance of the fund in the main form, which is called from within a DevExpress form. But it does not show any reaction. While this method works well in its original form.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what type `DataBaseContext` is.  More specifically, are you using EntityFramework -- is this a `DbContext` or [derived from it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext#defining-a-dbcontext-derived-class)?

Comment: Yes, I use Entity Framework exactly. I also use DbContext to retrieve information. But I did not understand what you mean by derivation. If possible, explain more